# Power BI reports don't automatically refresh

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report that sources from an Excel file on my laptop.  The visualizations are in Import / Scheduled Refresh mode (to be clear, not DirectQuery / Live Connection mode).  I am using the gateway in 'On-premises data gateway (personal mode)' to refresh my dataset in the service.  To my surprise, after refreshing the dataset, the corresponding charts in the report do not update automatically.  They only update after I click on 'Refresh' in the report itself.  This goes against the claim that the reports should be updated automatically, as documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data

How can I make the report update automatically after a dataset refresh?  Requiring my consumers to manually click on 'Refresh' is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should update automatically. I'm guessing what's happening is that the report you were viewing was cached in your browser to some extent.

Try opening in a different browser or incognito instead of hitting 'Refresh' to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the same browser, you can also open the DevTools and clear the site data as I've shown in the screenshot attached. this should clear the cache and reload the page with the updated data